# to keep files after kernel rebooting

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, kernel

i need to use reboot() system call (to reboot the kernel 2.6.29 with ARM) and i tried the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART);
}
```

it works well! but what im wondering is after rebooting the kernel im loosing the files being saved.
i mean if use this code, "url" file is not saved after reboot.

```
int main()
    {
        FILE *pFile = fopen("url", "a"); // for .txt file
        // write to file/read from file ... etc
        fclose(pFile);

        int fdUART = open("/dev/ttySAC0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
        // some operations on UART port
        close(fdUART);
        /* Ethernet raw package process*/
        /* Char dev driver open and communicate with FPGA fifo */
        /* so on */
        reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART);
    }
```

and am using the UART, Ethernet, char drivers and just would like to know reboot() call systems's effect to my system.

any help highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the device you're writing to isn't persistent. You may well just be writing into a tmpfs or something. What's mounted in the working directory of this program?

Comment: oh yeah.. i forget to tell that im writing the file ("url") to SDCard by mounting but file system is cramfs. and thx for helping me.

Comment: I soo you've written `close(pFile)`. That should be `fclose(pFile)`, as it's declared `FILE *pFile`. Are you sure this is your actual code?

Comment: I suggest calling the `sync(2)` and/or `fsync(2)`  system calls.

Answer (score 3):

You've written in the comments that the file system is cramfs.

From [the Wikipedia page for cramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramfs):

> The compressed ROM file system (or cramfs) is a free (GPL'ed) read-only Linux file system designed for simplicity and space-efficiency. It is mainly used in embedded systems and small-footprint systems.

Note that it's read-only: that means your changes won't be preserved.

You'll need to write to persistent storage to have your changes preserved.

Comment: yeap, you are 100% right but process goes like this:
I execute program, program mounts SDcard to /mn/ directory and writes files into it. When system needs to restart program unmounts /mnt/ directory and do  reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART);.
Question goes how to keep the files being written. Second question what is the side effects (to UART/Ethernet ports) to kernel when program suddenly restarts the kernel. (ps: sorry I guess I couldn't explain what i wanna ask.)